# Dual Switch with 3 black wires and 1 red wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, replacement, motion-sensor

I have an old dual light switch in the garage that I would like to replace with a motion controlled switch.

Since this is two switches I’m figuring I need to replace this dual switch with two motion controlled switches.

So I need to separate the wiring to this one switch into wiring for two switches. Part of that will be understanding the four wires on the current dual switch.

Can you help me understand what’s going on here? Also any suggestions on how to wire the two motion-controlled switches would be appreciated.

The switches each control three dual fluorescent fixtures, so six fixtures total. Pics below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the top switch a 3-way? That is, is there another switch that can also be used to control the same light fixtures?

Comment: I take it there's only one always-hot coming into this box?